# Dynamic allocation with malloc

Tags: c, malloc

In what ways is

```
int main(int argc, char **argv)
{
    int N = atoi(argv[1]);
    int v[N]; 

    ...some code here...
}
```

better than

```
int main(int argc, char **argv)
{
    int count = atoi(argv[1]);
    int *N = malloc(count * sizeof(int));
     ...some code here...

     free(N);
}
```

?

Is it less error-prone?

P.S: I know where the two will typically be allocated.

Edit: Initialized count.

Comment: Allocation on the stack (like the 1st case) is managed automatically (you don't have to explicitly allocate and free). On the other hand the stack is quite limited in size. The 2nd case is allocating on the heap which is usually significantly bigger, but requires manual management (alloc/free).

Comment: @HarisSalam thanks for fixing it. I wrote an answer and will clean up my comment here :)

Comment: The second nicely handles `count == 0` whereas the first is UB.  Both have lots of issues with `count < 0`.

Comment: That can be rectified with input validation/error checking? The second one, that is, as the first one is inherently ineffective. Would you like to elaborate on your comment?

Comment: You should check that `argc >= 2` before using `argv[1]` in the calls to `atoi()`.  You should probably also check that `atoi()` returns neither zero nor a negative value before allocating the array. You should also check that `N` is not too large (using a limit such as 256,000) before trying to allocate the space with `int v[N];`

Comment: @JonathanLeffler Absolutely agree. :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's not "better" per se. It does a different thing:

```
    int v[count];
```

is a [*variable-length array*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Variable-length_array) in C99 and later. That means it has a *lifetime*: The moment it goes out of scope (the function in which it was created is finished), it's forgotten.

```
    int *N = malloc(count * sizeof(int));
```

on the other hand allocates that memory on the heap. That means it lives as long as you do not explicitly `free` it (or the program ends, which is at the end of your `main`, anyway, so this might not be the best code to illustrate the difference on)!

Now, having to remember that you have allocated some memory that you need to deallocate later is a hassle. Programmers get that wrong all the time, and that leads to either *memory leaks* (you forgetting to free memory you're not using anymore, leading to the memory used by a program growing over time) or *use-after-free bugs* (you using memory after you've already freed it, which has undefined results and can lead to serious bugs, including security problems).

On the other hand, your stack space is small. Like 4 kB or 8 kB. Try passing `1048576` to your program as `argv[1]`! That's a meager 1 million `int`s you're creating. And that probably means you're allocating 4 MB of RAM. 4 MB, compared to the Gigabytes of RAM your computer most likely has, that's simply not much data, right?

But your `int v[1048576]` would plainly fail, because that's more than a function is allowed to have "scratchpad" space for itself. So, in general, for variable-length things where you cannot know before that they are *really* small, your second solution with `malloc` is "better", because it actually works.

General remark: Memory management in C is hard. That's why languages (C++ and others) have come up with solutions where you can have something that can be made aware of its own lifetime, so that you cannot forget to `delete` something,  because the object itself knows when it is no longer used.